# Is it true that convolving a 3x3 matrix and a Full HD image is slower with FFT?

Tags: fft

Is it true that convolving a 3x3 matrix and a Full HD (1920×1080) image is slower with FFT, than with normal for-loops? Because you have to do zeropadding to get to a power of 2? (with the traditional Cooley-Tukey FFT for example)

Because when using the FFT, you have to zeropad the 3x3 kernel as well...
log(1920*1080)/log(2) is roughly 21.  That means I need 21 adds and 15.5 multiplies is 36.5 operations for each pixels. But I need to do 2 FFT and one IFFT. So, I need to multiply 36.5 by 3: 36.5*3=109.5 operations for each pixel?

When calculating the convolution directly using for-loops, you need 9 multiplications and 9 additions = 18 operations for each pixel.

I guess I made a mistake somewhere. One of those is '21 multiplies'... Please provide a better mathmatical proof.

Comment: Please stop simultaneously crossposting on multiple forums!  http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12217/is-it-true-that-convolving-a-3x3-matrix-and-a-full-hd-image-is-slower-with-fft.  Post on one forum or the other, and if your question doesn't get an adequate response after a couple of days request the moderator to move to the other forum.

Comment: As @WanderingLogic says, please stop duplicate posting. It is against the spirit of the SE series of sites. Please choose one site, and ask there. If it's off-topic for the site, the moderators will move it.

Comment: Re-opening after duplicate was removed from sister site.

Comment: As well as not cross-posting, it might also be a good idea to stick to just the one user account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably correct. Frequency domain convolution is typically only worthwhile for larger kernels. For convolution in the spatial domain the number of operations tends to increases as a square law with kernel dimension, whereas frequency domain convolution is constant time. The "tipping point" tends to be at kernel dimensions of the order of 10s of pixels, e.g. 31x31.

So, rule of thumb: for small kernels use direct convolution, for large kernels do it in the frequency domain.

Comment: When do you really need kernel dimensions like 31x31? But  log(1920*1080)/log(2) is roughly 21 operations in total OR 21 additions and 21 multiplications = 42 operations in total?

Comment: It's not at all unusual to have filter kernels this large (or even larger). There are also mathematically similar operations such as cross-correlation, e.g. for template matching, where the "kernel" is the same size as the target image. Note that for frequency domain convolution (or correlation) there are two forward FFTs and one reverse FFT, so you probably need to multiply your operation count by 3 (or possibly just 2, since one forward FFT can usually be amortised, as it's normally constant).

Comment: " two forward FFTs and one reverse FFT" Why 2 forward and one reverse? And not 1 forward and 1 reverse? Again: log(1920*1080)/log(2) is roughly 21 operations in total OR 21 additions and 21 multiplications = 42 operations in total?

Comment: Do you think this formula is correct for a 2D-FFT? And I don't need to round N to a power of 2?

Comment: To clarify further: you need to transform both your image and your kernel to the frequency domain, so that's 2 x forward FFTs. Then after multiplying in the frequency domain you need to apply an inverse FFT on the product to get back to the spatial domain. So 2 x forward FFT and 1 x inverse FFT in total (although one of the forward FFTs typically needs to be done only once).

Comment: The rounding to power of 2 we've already covered - if your FFT is radix 2 only then you need to round up to a power of 2. For a mixed radix FFT, e.g. FFTW, then you can do better.

Comment: You wrote "For a 2D FFT you have to do m x 1D FFTs in each axis so that's O(2 m^2 log m) = O(m^2 log m)" I took O(N log_2 N) With N=1920×1080 That isn't incorrect? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514861/computational-complexity-of-the-fft-in-n-dimensions

Comment: An answer at MATH.SE talks about a 2D FFT with a complexity of  "$2N_1N_2(\log_2 N_1+\log_2 N_2)=2N_1N_2\log_2(N_1N_2)$" You had an answer without the 2 in front. How is that possible? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400251

Comment: It depends on whether you want Big O complexity or actual number of operations, and if you want the latter you have to define what an operation is, i.e. scalar versus complex add/multiply.

Comment: Does '2N1N2log2(N1N2)' already involve the operations you need for the Inverse Fourier Transform?

Comment: That's just for one FFT (forward or reverse - they are the same). You need two or three FFTs for convolution.

Comment: No, it's a *lot* more than that - you dropped the N factor.

Comment: @Paul_R "You need two or three FFTs for convolution" When does it make sense to only use 2 FFTs instead of 3?

Comment: I explained that earlier - if the filter kernel is known ahead of time, and is constant, and you are going to be processing multiple images with the same kernel, then you can just FFT the (padded) kernel once, and store the frequency domain representation. Then you just need to FFT each image, multiply by the preprocessed kernel, then IFFT back again to the spatial domain.

Comment: Do I need to add 1 to the total amount of operations, because of the multiplication in the Fourier domain, after the Fourier Transform?

Comment: The multiplication is just one *complex* multiply per point, so that's 4 scalar multiplies + 2 scalar additions.

Comment: You're mixing up complex operations and scalar operations I think. Note from earlier discussions: if you just have a 3x3 kernel then it's pointless to continue looking at frequency domain implementations.

Comment: log(1920*1080)/log(2) is roughly 21. That means I need 21 complex adds and 10.5 complex multiplies for each pixel (because FFT can be computed in $\frac{N}{2}\log N$ complex multiplies and complex $N\log N$ additions)? Why do I need to convert that to real adds and multiplies in the first place? And why is 1 complex addition , 2 real additions??

Comment: Please ask another question on this forum, and accept this answer for the current question. This comment train is being flagged by the system as excessive. Use a chat room if you need discussion. Comments are not the place for discussion.